# Как перевести етот код с jQuery на чистий JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#menu" ).click(function() {
    $( "#nav" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
   });
  });
})
```

Comment: Пометьте вопрос `html` и Sebastopol вам без всяких JS, на чистом CSS сделает. И круче будет.

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var btnMenu = document.getElementsById("menu");
    var navNode = document.getElementsById("nav");

    btnMenu.addEventListener("click", function(){
        navNode.classList.toggle("active");
    }, false);
})
```

CSS:

```
#nav {  
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s; // or something other
    transform: translate(0, -100%); // or something other 
}
#nav.active{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 100%); 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо очень. Хороша робота 